# How to speed up TortoiseSVN to VisualSVN server through SSH tunnel?

Tags: performance, svn, networking, ssh, tunnel

This is our current setup: Windows Server 2008 with Visual SVN Server. On the client side we use tortoise svn.

Inside the company (internal network), the access speed(checkout,update,commit) is good.

When we access from outside the company via our SSH tunnel, it becomes really slow.

I read that there could be a few possibilities:

- usage of HTTPS vs SVN (VisualSVN doesnt support SVN protocol :(  )
- antivirus (did not test it yet)

Any other suggestions ? Thank you

Comment: can you test the speed of simple file tranfer via ssh?

Comment: may be your tunnel is configured incorrectly, and ssh is your bottleneck